# Regex matching up to two words

Tags: regex

I want to create the Regex that will match only up to words (no numbers), and will treat two words separated by space as one string, and if there are two words, both of them have to start with capital letter.

So for example:

"String" -> Match

"Two Strings" -> Match

"One Two Three" -> no match (string has more than two words)

"1 word" -> no match (string contains one or more digits)

"Two strings" -> no match (one of the strings doesn't start with capital letter)

I tried to make one big regular expression in different ways but it doesn't work. Help really appreaciated.

EDIT: I don't know if it's possible to make one big Regex for it, or should I seperate it into couple smaller ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

```
^([A-Z][a-z]*( [A-Z][a-z]*)?)$
```

matches any one or two words that each start with a capital letter and have zero or more lowercase letters following.
Matches: "Yes", "Two Strings", "A B"
Does not match: "Y3s", "Two strings", "One Two Three", "Player 1"

If capital letters inside the words are allowed (like "JavaScript") you can use:

```
 ^([A-Z][A-Za-z]*( [A-Z][A-Za-z]*)?)$
```

If you also want numbers and underscores inside your words allowed (like "C00k13_") use:

```
^([A-Z]\w*( [A-Z]\w*)?)$
```

Btw:
The `^` (starting with) and `$` (ending with) ensure that only the whole string can be a match.
E.g.:
"Alpha Beta Gamma" -> No match
"Alpha Beta" -> Match

A quick demo: [regexr.com/5381r](https://regexr.com/5381r)

Comment: Thank you! This will do just fine!

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish:

`^[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+$|^[A-Z][a-z]+$`

You can see a regex101.com demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/7ESXmE/1)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to the problem would be this regular expression.

`^([A-Z][a-z]*(\s?)+){1,2}\s*$`

Here I have grouped what constitutes a word i.e `([A-Z][a-z]*(\s?)+)`.

And then have just matched it one to two times.

If you want to match it one to three times you can simply replace 2 with three or any number you wish to match the word for.

Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/tb8knC/2) regex sandbox.

Comment: Thank you, this will do!